# What is the total mass of leaves on an 'average' mid-latitude deciduous tree?

Tags: botany, trees, forestry

I know that this is a broad question as there are a very large number of different species of tree with all manner of profiles, height, leaf sizes, etc. My ultimate goal is to estimate the total mass of leaves that fall each autumn in both the Northern and Southern Hemispheres, separately. It seems appropriate to ask for a single tree to start with, hence this question. If there is a better way to get to the final 'ultimate' answer, feel free to post it.

Comment: You might have better luck asking how much leaf litter falls on a unit area of forested ground on average, I suspect that at least has estimates. Per tree will never give anything reliable due to the wide varieties and sizes of trees.

Comment: There's a big difference between the mass of the leaves on the tree, and the mass when they fall and dry out.  Anecdotally, I'd guesstimate that the leaves from my large maple tree that I rake up in fall (when they're quite dry) weigh a couple of kg or so - say maybe 5-20 kg if you count the ones that blow into the neighbors' yards.